# Optimizing MySQL query for integer range search

Tags: mysql, indexing, query-optimization

I have over 1.7 million records in a table which contains ip address range(begin and end) both primary key and corresponding details.

The Table structure is

```
mysql> desc csv;
+---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field   | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| begin   | bigint(20)  | NO   | PRI | 0       |       |
| end     | bigint(20)  | NO   | PRI | 0       |       |
| code    | char(2)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| country | varchar(50) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| city    | varchar(50) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| area    | varchar(50) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Because of Indexing in Primary Key, the search is fast when an exact match is to be made like this

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM csv WHERE begin=3338456576;
+------------+------------+------+---------------+----------+---------------+
| begin      | end        | code | country       | city     | area          |
+------------+------------+------+---------------+----------+---------------+
| 3338456576 | 3338456831 | US   | UNITED STATES | NEW YORK | NEW YORK CITY |
+------------+------------+------+---------------+----------+---------------+
1 row in set (0.03 sec)
```

But when I try to search within a range, It takes longer time.

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM csv WHERE begin<3338456592 AND end>3338456592;
+------------+------------+------+---------------+----------+---------------+
| begin      | end        | code | country       | city     | area          |
+------------+------------+------+---------------+----------+---------------+
| 3338456576 | 3338456831 | US   | UNITED STATES | NEW YORK | NEW YORK CITY |
+------------+------------+------+---------------+----------+---------------+
1 row in set (1.59 sec)
```

Is there any way I can optimize my query to search ip address within a range?

**EDIT**

Create table Statement

```
CREATE TABLE `csv` (
  `begin` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `end` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `code` char(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `country` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `city` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `area` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`begin`,`end`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: Can you also post the create table statement output? And some explain statements outputs?

Comment: How many rows the query returns ? Could you post a result of `SELECT count(*) FROM csv WHERE begin<3338456592 AND end>3338456592;' ?

Comment: Really only one row ? That means that all remaining rows meet the opposite condition `begin > 3338456592 AND end < 3338456592`.  Assuming that `begin <= end` (is my assumption true?), then 1.7 million records must have `begin = end = 3338456592`, and only one row has `begin <> 3338456592 AND end <> 3338456592`, am I right ?

Comment: @kordirko take a look at [this link showing 20 rows from my table.](http://pastebin.com/embed_js.php?i=LDW5v1U3)

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7955382/between-statement-missing-indexes-in-certain-cases/7963846#7963846

Comment: Are you sure you want to use `<` and `>` in the query? From the data in your table, I would suppose you need `<=` and `>=`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the IP ranges are not overlapping, so the query is never going to return more than 1 row, you can use this:

```
SELECT q.*
FROM 
  ( SELECT csv.* 
    FROM csv
    WHERE csv.begin < 3338456592 
    ORDER BY csv.begin DESC
    LIMIT 1
  ) AS q
WHERE 3338456592 < q.end ;
```

No index needs to be added. The primary index will be used.

Comment: Great!! Did it in 0.06 Seconds. Thanx

Comment: Removing the last line also works. It gave result in `0.0 seconds`

Comment: Keep the last line. Otherwise you may get false positives.

Answer (score 1):

In case the ranges are overlapping you should:

- define the ip range as a LineString column
- define spatial index on that column
- use a geometric "contains" query

See more in [Efficient data model for range queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20540254/efficient-data-model-for-range-queries)

Answer (score 0):

What score on `SELECT begin, end, code, country, city, area FROM csv WHERE begin <> 3338456592 HAVING begin NOT BETWEEN MIN(begin) AND MAX(end)`?

**UPD**:
It is my version of table structure.

```
CREATE TABLE `csv` (
  `begin` INT(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `end` INT(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `code` char(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `country` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `city` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `area` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `combined` (`begin`,`end`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I think use country and code as ENUM it is faster.

Comment: Looks like an impossible SQL to me...  begin = 3338456592   MIN(begin) = 0   MAX(begin) = 4294967295  and begin 3338456592 is NOT BETWEEN those values?

Comment: @GauravSharma Actauly we cant try to optimize your table structure. What returns `SELECT * FROM csv PROCEDURE ANALYSE();`?

Comment: @GauravSharma and can you change table engine to `myisam`? It faster than `innodb`

Comment: @GauravSharma and create complex index instead of that those 2.
`KEY combined (begin, end)`

Comment: result of [SELECT * FROM csv PROCEDURE ANALYSE();](http://pastebin.com/embed_js.php?i=ZF0dqWnB)

Comment: changing DB Engine to `myisam' did it in `0.45 seconds`

Comment: It is 1.04sec totally now?

Comment: @Max MyISAM isn't faster then InnoDB if you configure the server good... read this http://www.oracle.com/partners/en/knowledge-zone/mysql-5-5-innodb-myisam-522945.pdf   "Read Only Results InnoDB delivered 4.6x higher throughput than MyISAM"  and "Read Write Results  InnoDB delivered 35x higher throughput than MyISAM"   oeps your thoery out of the window...

Comment: @RaymondNijland I changed my Engine to myisam and found that it performed the same query in `0.45 sec`, earlier with innodb was `1.59 sec`. While changing primary key to combined didn't made any difference.

Comment: @Gaurav Sharma i had read it.. but still this means your server isn't correctly configured for using InnoDB.. because it's proven that InnoDB is the fasted storage engine within MySQL.

Comment: @GauravSharma can you show me result of last actual SQL request, but wit `EXPLAIN` word in the beginning of the line: `EXPLAIN SELECT...`

Comment: @RaymondNijland Server must better configured before using InnoDB than MyISAM. But I agree with you that MyISAM no always faster than InnoDB.

Comment: Oeps full table scan there that's an NO go.. but why are you trying to range scan do i mis something here? the next begin value should be the prev end value + 1 or i'am i wrong?

Comment: @GauravSharma please change `bigint(20)` to `int(10)` and try execute query with SELECTed fields `begin, end, code, country, city, area`. And what result of seconds. Thanks

Comment: @Max int cannot hold the ip addresses.

Comment: @GauravSharma emm what about UNSIGNED INT(10) ?

Comment: UNSIGNED INT can indeed hold the max off 4294967295 IP 255.255.255.255  you can remove (10) this is only usable with zerofill... i see this sometimes INT(11) without zerofill don't know maybe the programmer is thinking the int can hold an larger value that way...

Comment: i cannot modify the data type, getting an error may be because begin is a keyeword. will try aftr some time