# Mysql not using index when a length is different

Tags: mysql, indexing

found this interesting issue with the MYSQL recently. Spent hours reading on the net and still unable to come up with a solution.

a large table is described as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE `ip_country_region_city` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`ip_from` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
`ip_to` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
 .........
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `ipindex` (`ip_from`,`ip_to`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=16908031 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

This table is used for ip-range search.

The following query is used a a sample/test query:

```
SELECT * FROM ip_country_region_city
WHERE   455141527   BETWEEN ip_from AND ip_to
```

Where 455141527 is a given IP address represented as a number for 27.32.232.151

MYSQL will then utilise an "ipindex" for above IP Address.
However, should we provide this query with a different IP address that represents into a 10 digit number i.e. 3159544575 for 188.82.206.157 mysql won't utilise 'ipindex' at all.

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM ip_country_region_city
WHERE  INET_ATON("27.32.232.151")    BETWEEN ip_from AND ip_to
```

returns that it's using the above mentioned index

```
1   SIMPLE  ip_country_region_city  range   ipindex ipindex 4       746392  Using where
```

but

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM ip_country_region_city
WHERE  INET_ATON("188.82.206.157")    BETWEEN ip_from AND ip_to
```

returns NULL as index used

```
1   SIMPLE  ip_country_region_city  ALL ipindex             6716010 Using where
```

Your assistance is appreciated

Comment: What is the `explain select ...` output?

Comment: first as juergen d said we need the explain of the select. secone have you tried to write the query a bit differently?

Comment: tried using both INET_ATON and converting the IP manually. Also I've updated the question. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to

[Optimizing MySQL query for integer range search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19456564/optimizing-mysql-query-for-integer-range-search)

I was able to rebuild this query and make it work,